# TASKLIST Restart a program that crashed

Tags: batch-file

Why doesn't it work ? If the program crashes i want it to restart.

```
 tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq filezilla.exe" /fi "status eq running" | find  /i "filezilla.exe"  > nul && ( 
exit
) || ( 
echo Server is not running or not responding
taskkill /f /im filezilla.exe
timeout 10
start C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to start `C:\Program` with three paramters: `Files\FileZilla`, `FTP` and `Client\filezilla.exe`.

You have to quote paths/filenames with spaces.
Because `start` takes the first quoted parameter as windows title, give it a dummy title:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe"
```

Note: there should no need to use `start` with an EXE. Just:

```
"C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe"
```

should also work.